# How should I prepare for an interdisciplinary interview?

Tags: phd, interview, interdisciplinary

I applied for a Ph.D. internship position in a protein research lab. They invited me to appear for an online interview.

My background is in IT, and the professor who will interview me is from Chemistry. How should I prepare for the interview?

Comment: What do you know of Chemistry or protein research? Would your position be one of providing software support for modeling? IT is pretty broad. What is your specialty within it?

Comment: @Buffy, *What do you know of Chemistry or protein research?* --- I know protein from the computational point of view. I.e., protein geometry. *Would your position be one of providing software support for modeling?* --- computational protein design. *What is your specialty within it?* --- protein modeling, and simulation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments, you seem pretty well situated already for such an interview. It is impossible to know what you will be asked, but be prepared to to discuss modeling in general. Don't be put off by questions for which you have no immediate answer. Most people will accept that you need to look into things further and that not every problem is easy.

Flexibility is your friend.